# No data retrieved from MySQL to Android ListView

Tags: php, android, mysql, listview

I'm trying to display data from `MySQL` server to android, but no data are shown.

Data are not able to retrieve out to Android `ListView`. But I can see
data get displayed on my localhost.

**RetrieveInformation**

```
 String myJSON;
    JSONArray information = null;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> infoList;

   infoList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
   listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView2);

       public void getData() {
            class GetDataJSON extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

                @Override
                protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
                    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.107.115:80/Android/CRUD/retrieveInformation.php");

                    // Depends on your web service
                    httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

                    InputStream inputStream = null;
                    String result = null;
                    try {
                        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                        inputStream = entity.getContent();
                        // json is UTF-8 by default
                        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                        String line = null;
                        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                        {
                            sb.append(line + "\n");
                        }
                        result = sb.toString();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // Oops
                    }
                    finally {
                        try{if(inputStream != null)inputStream.close();}catch(Exception squish){}
                    }
                    return result;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(String result){
                    myJSON=result;
                    showList();
                }
            }
            GetDataJSON g = new GetDataJSON();
            g.execute();
        }

        protected void showList(){
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(myJSON);
                information = jsonObj.getJSONArray(Config.TAG_RESULTS);

                for(int i=0;i<information.length();i++){
                    JSONObject c = information.getJSONObject(i);
                    String date = c.getString(Config.TAG_DATE);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),date,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    String timeIn = c.getString(Config.TAG_TiME_IN);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),timeIn,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    String timeOut = c.getString(Config.TAG_TIME_OUT);

                    HashMap<String,String> info = new HashMap<String,String>();
                    info.put(Config.TAG_DATE, date);
                   info.put(Config.TAG_TiME_IN, timeIn);
                   info.put(Config.TAG_TIME_OUT,timeOut);

                    infoList.add(info);
                }

                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        HomePage.this, infoList, R.layout.retrieve_data,
                        new String[]{Config.TAG_DATE,Config.TAG_TiME_IN,Config.TAG_TIME_OUT},
                        new int[]{R.id.date,R.id.timeIn,R.id.timeOut}
                );

                listView.setAdapter(adapter);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

**retrieveInformation.php**

```
<?php
  define('HOST','127.0.0.1:3307');
  define('USER','root');
  define('PASS','');
  define('DB','androiddb');

  $con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB) or die('unable to connect');

  $sql = "select * from information";

  $res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

  $result=array();

  while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
      array_push($result,array('id'=>$row[0],'name'=>$row[1],'weather'=>$row[2],'date'=>$row[3],'status'=>$row[4],
      'time_in'=>$row[5], 'time_out'=>$row[6]));
  }

 echo (json_encode(array("result"=>$result)));

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

**Browser**

[image]

**retrieve_data.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:padding="12dp">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:paddingLeft="6dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/l21"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:maxLines="1">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="210dp"
                android:textSize="10dp"
                android:id="@+id/date"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/l21"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TimeIn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/secondary_text_dark_nodisable"
                android:text="Time In     : "
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:ellipsize="end" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/timeIn" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll3"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ll2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/secondary_text_dark_nodisable"
                android:text="Time Out  : "
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:layout_below="@+id/TimeIn"
                android:id="@+id/TimeOut" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/timeOut"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/TimeOut"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: hi .i have few questions.first check the respone what you are getting from server.next check once weather the hit is going to server or not.next change the local ip and keep global ip

Comment: Is there away I can check whether there are data retrieved to showlist () ?

Comment: open php file on your browser to see what output it is producing, you can also use [POSTman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en) a chrome extension to check the request/response

Comment: Also in Android you can read response in one line code using EntityUtil class as String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());  This will be better than using inputstream and using loops

Comment: Data get displayed on browser

Comment: Please update your question with a sample of the JSON that your PHP file prints.

Comment: Also, the XML for `R.layout.retrieve_data`

Comment: @cricket_007 My table have 7 column, but I just want to retrieve `date`, `timeIn` and `timeOut` only

Comment: @cricket_007 I have solved it...thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for those who are trying to help me. Finally I solved it.

The `Config.TAG.xxx` should always same with the column name. Data cannot retrieved if the column 
name and TAG are different...

Answer (score 1):

use "echo" operator on your server instead print (or with print)

Comment: I have changed to  `echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));`, but still no data displayed :/

Answer (score 0):

Use **echo operator** than print.

echo has no return value while print has a return value of 1 so it can be used in expressions. echo can take multiple parameters (although such usage is rare) while print can take only one argument. echo is marginally faster than print.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you are getting a normal server response code on the execution of your request or a error from 500 series HTTP codes. Try to debug your php code by printing some variables from the start of the code and checking responses on client side.