# App crashed when JSONObject get called

Tags: android, mysql, json, listview

I wanted to retrieve the data from MySQL to android listView. I have follow each single steps from this [tutorial](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-json-parsing-retrieve-from-mysql-database/), however it crashed when I trying to call JSON object. Please help. Thanks a lot..

```
 private ListView listView;
  String myJSON;
  JSONArray information = null;
  ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> infoList;

         @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        infoList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView2);
        getData();
  }
      public void getData() {
                class GetDataJSON extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

                    @Override
                    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
                        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.107.115:80/Android/CRUD/retrieveInformation.php");

                        // Depends on your web service
                        httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

                        InputStream inputStream = null;
                        String result = null;
                        try {
                            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                            inputStream = entity.getContent();
                            // json is UTF-8 by default
                            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
                            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                            String line = null;
                            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                            {
                                sb.append(line + "\n");
                            }
                            result = sb.toString();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            // Oops
                        }
                        finally {
                            try{if(inputStream != null)inputStream.close();}catch(Exception squish){}
                        }
                        return result;
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
                        myJSON=result;
                        showList();
                    }
                }
                GetDataJSON g = new GetDataJSON();
                g.execute();
            }

            protected void showList(){
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(myJSON);
                    information = jsonObj.getJSONArray(Config.TAG_RESULTS);

                    for(int i=0;i<information.length();i++){
                        JSONObject c = information.getJSONObject(i);
                        String date = c.getString(Config.TAG_DATE);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),date,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        String timeIn = c.getString(Config.TAG_TiME_IN);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),timeIn,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        String timeOut = c.getString(Config.TAG_TIME_OUT);

                        HashMap<String,String> info = new HashMap<String,String>();
                        info.put(Config.TAG_DATE, date);
                        info.put(Config.TAG_TiME_IN, timeIn);
                        info.put(Config.TAG_TIME_OUT,timeOut);

                        infoList.add(info);
                    }

                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                            HomePage.this, infoList, R.layout.retrieve_data,
                            new String[]{Config.TAG_DATE,Config.TAG_TiME_IN,Config.TAG_TIME_OUT},
                            new int[]{R.id.date,R.id.timeIn,R.id.timeOut}
                    );

                    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
```

**retrieveInformation.php**

```
<?php
  define('HOST','127.0.0.1:3307');
  define('USER','root');
  define('PASS','');
  define('DB','androiddb');

  $con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB) or die('unable to connect');

  $sql = "select * from information";

  $res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

  $result=array();

  while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
      array_push($result,array('id'=>$row[0],'name'=>$row[1],'weather'=>$row[2],'date'=>$row[3],'status'=>$row[4],
      'time_in'=>$row[5], 'time_out'=>$row[6]));
  }

 print(json_encode(array("result"=>$result)));

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

**LogCat**

```
  Process: com.example.project.myapplication, PID: 31622
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at org.json.JSONTokener.nextCleanInternal(JSONTokener.java:116)
            at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:94)
            at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:155)
            at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:172)
            at com.example.project.myapplication.GUI.HomePage.showList(HomePage.java:185)
            at com.example.project.myapplication.GUI.HomePage$1GetDataJSON.onPostExecute(HomePage.java:176)
            at com.example.project.myapplication.GUI.HomePage$1GetDataJSON.onPostExecute(HomePage.java:137)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
```

**Code**

```
`JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(myJSON);` ,
```

`class GetDataJSON extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {`
 and  `showList();`.

Comment: where is the error pointed in the code?

Comment: @shreyansjain you can see the **Code**

Comment: where is line 185 i can't count it.

Comment: @shreyansjain Three lines get pointed. I have posted in **Code**, below the **LogCat**

Comment: check your `myJSON` string, it might be null

Comment: Do you call `showList` before `getData`? `myJSON` will be null if you do. Can you post the whole activity code you have?

Comment: @cricket_007 from `onPostExecute()` only he is calling `showList()`

Comment: @RRR - I see that, but where is getData called? OnCreate? I don't see that anywhere

Comment: @cricket_007 check again..Edited.

Comment: @RRR How to check `myJSON` string ?

Comment: Hmm. Looks okay.... I would check if `result` is null in `onPostExecute`. Not sure why it would be, though

Comment: @cricket_007 How to check whether result is null or not ? Data in php get displayed on browser.

Comment: You can use `Log.d()`, but the `result` would be null if you were having an exception thrown by the HTTP connection stuff. You really should never squash an exception. Just a guess, but do you have the internet permission in your manifest?

Comment: @cricket_007 ya,I have

Comment: If I remove the showList(), app does not crashed..What's wrong here :/

Comment: It doesn't crash because you are not parsing a null (or invalid JSON) string.

Comment: @cricket_007 really frustrated

Comment: Really not sure what to tell you. I see you are using print in your PHP code instead of echo like the tutorial. Are you sure you are using the correct ip address and URL? Just log the value of myJSON in showList before you parse it; learn to debug, the line of the error is pretty clear, but your code looks fine logically.

Comment: @cricket_007 I forgot to open  wifi-connection

Comment: See? Silliest of things causing us devs to waste our time! Glad you fixed it.

Comment: @cricket_007 Thanks for pointing out my mistakes..But no data displayed on list view...

Comment: @cricket_007 please see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34544643/no-data-retrieved-from-mysql-to-android-listview)

Comment: @cricket_007 Is there a way I can display a "no data connection" instead of the app crashed ?

Comment: You need to implement proper exception handling. For example, for each JSON key you try to receive, you need to make sure it exists in the data. You also need to see if you get any data at all from the server. I'm sure if you make a new question someone would be willing to give you an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a stupid mistake again. forget to switch on the wifi-connection